# Remove characters from PostgreSQL database causing encoding errors

Tags: postgresql, encoding, unicode, postgresql-10

I have a PostgreSQL 10 database that uses WIN1252 encoding.

One of my columns has values that cause conversion errors when running a select from pgAdmin 4:

`SELECT myfield FROM mydb.myschema."MYTABLE"`

Returns:

```
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0x9d in encoding "WIN1252" has no 
equivalent in encoding "UTF8"
SQL state: 22P05
```

Setting the client encoding to WIN1252 in pgAdmin 4 causes it to drop the connection to the database (I remember reading somewhere that pgAdmin 4 has issues with setting the client encoding, but track down the link).

Using psql and setting the client encoding to WIN1252, selecting one of the offending features:

```
SELECT myfield
FROM mydb.myschema."MYTABLE"
WHERE oid = 12345
```

Returns:

`â€œA sample comment`

Looking at the data that was originally imported into the DB, it appears that “curly quotes” were incorrectly imported.

Is there a way to remove these characters from the column - either replacing them with regular quotation marks, or simply deleting them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the WIN1252 character set:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 , there is no character corresponding to that hexadecimal code `9D`. The same goes for `81`, `8D`, `8F`, `90`.

That's why it "has not equivalent" in UTF8: that character doesn't exist in the first place in the source map.

It doesn't error out when displayed or input in a session configured in `WIN1252` encoding. When using the proper code page (`chcp 1252`) with psql.exe on top of cmd.exe, these characters are displayed in my environment as a question mark inside a rectangular box.

Anyway, you might want to remove these with statements like (when using the WIN1252 client encoding):

```
UPDATE tablename SET field=replace(field, chr(x'9D'::int), '')
  WHERE strpos(field,chr(x'9D'::int))>0;
```

Use psql if WIN1252 is unusable with PgAdmin. Once these characters are removed, you'll be able to switch later to UTF8 client encoding.

Comment: Perfect! I looked at that Wikipedia page before, but got confused when I couldn't find 9D.

Comment: If the database is encoded in WIN1252, how did it get inserted into the database with that invalid character sequence to begin with? (Why didn't PostgreSQL reject the input)

Comment: @EvanCarroll I dumped the data from an SQL_ASCII database, and restored it into the WIN1252 database - my guess is something went wrong here.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: AFAICS the current PG code accepts any non-zero byte in WIN1252 and probably other monobyte encodings. Why it does that and should it be more strict would be questions for the developers. There might be performance or compatibility tradeoffs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're reading it backwards. Instead try to `SET` the client_encoding to `utf8`;.

```
SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'utf8';
```

Comment: this works; but how do we make this permanent?